# lsof counterpart for a JVM?

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, lsof

`lsof` is a nice tool for Unix, showing all currently open file handles.

Does anyone know a similar tool that would show all open files inside a running JVM (via JVMTI or any similar interface)?

In this particular case, it would be sufficient for me to know which class has a handle open. Method/line or even an entire chain to GC root would be fantastic, but handler owner class is already a good start.

I know I could make a heap dump, open it in a profiler and find this out, but this is a tedious task, especially for the big heaps.

Comment: I would suggest you use a better profiler. ;) In YourKit I can see all the open files while the application is running.

Comment: I use YourKit, but you rarely have profiling enabled on live environments. Or does YourKit support showing file handles from dumps?

Comment: It supports showing FileDescriptor from a dump by searching by class which is used for all open files. You can see where references to any file are being held.

Answer (score 1):

The JVMTI option sounds like it wouldn't be a bad choice. The big issue would be ensuring you wrap everything that may open a file handle: you would basically have to go through the JDK source code and find every native function that did a file open (littered throughout java.io.*, java.nio.*, I'd think java.net.* as well if you consider sockets as file handles, and just about everywhere else that a file handle may be opened by a native function) and then wrap them all with the [SetNativeMethodPrefix](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#SetNativeMethodPrefix) call.

I'm assuming that is what some of the profiling folks do: however if you're not required to do this listing in real time then I'd think it would be WAY easier to use `lsof` or `handle` (on Windows platforms) and filter for your JVM's process id.